# How to load the Sound module?

Tags: audio, julia

Please would you know how to sucessfully load the sound module with Julia ? At the prompt I type the following and I immediately obtain the following error :

```
julia> require("Sound")
ERROR: Sound not found
 in require at loading.jl:39
```

I am using linux Mint.

Answer (score 3):

First, which version of Julia are you using? Use the `versioninfo()` command at the REPL.

Second, have you installed the `Sound.jl` package using `Pkg.add("Sound")`?

Finally, to use the sound package, use `using Sound`, or `import Sound` - see manual for the difference.

Comment: My version of Julia is 0.3.3 (2014-10-21 20:18 UTC). When I tried to install Sound.jl using this command I got : Pkg.add("Sound")
INFO: Initializing package repository /home/monsieur/.julia/v0.3
INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
ERROR: unknown package Sound

Comment: Ah looking at pkg.julialang.org it seems there is no Sound package. I seem to remember it from the early days of Julia. Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: I am just beginning in Julia but I wanted to directly apply what I learn to sound processing so I found this page [link](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.1/stdlib/sound/) but now I am stuck.

Comment: That's the documentation for Julia 0.1 - very old. You should follow the link from the Julia homepage. There are some good audio packages like DSP.jl and AudioIO.jl that you should check out